# Face clustering by similiarity

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, face-recognition

I'm using Luxand Face API to detect faces and extract a byte vector (named TemplateId) from it. Using this i can compare similiarity between two faces.

Now assuming I have a lot of templates in my set I'd like to cluster them so that each cluster would contain faces from one person. More briefly: i've got a *big* set of items and similiarity function for a pair of items. How can I cluster this set?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that should be easy.  First, as the frames come in, you can extract a template with every frame.  Its up to you how many frames you process.  Second, if you are using the Tracker API, then you can continue to feed frames to tracker and it will continue to 'learn' the subject or its maximum memory setting is reached, at which point it will start learning.

I feed 5 frames for each subject and store all the 5 templates and the tracker for that subject in a record that holds these values.